# Prove or disprove. If $a$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then there exists an integer $k>1$ such that $a^k=[1]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n>1$ be an integer, and let $a∈\mathbb{Z}_n$. Prove or disprove the following statement.
If $a$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then there exists an integer $k>1$ such that $a^k=[1]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

My main thoughts so far are that because $a$ is a unit, $gcd(a, n) = 1$, and there exists another number in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ that when multiplied with $a$ they equal 1. I think there are also specific cases where an element has a multiplicative inverse as itself, but I don't know whether that could be generalized. I know that if an integer $k$ were to exist then there could be an integer $x$ such that $nx = a^k - 1$. I'm thinking it's true but I'm not sure how to go from here to either prove or disprove.

Could someone please help?

Comment: If $a$ is a unit, then by Lagrange $a\in U(n)$ has an order dividing the order of $U(n)$, which is $\phi(n)$. Hence $a^k=1$ in $U(n)$.

Comment: Is there a another way to explain that? I still don't quite understand that terminology.

Comment: @user973299 - In a finite group $G$ with $n$ elements any element $a\in G$ has the property that $a^n=1$ is the identity $1$. If not, the subgroup $\{a^k:k \geq 0\}$ would have more than $n$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes a way to do this "without" using group theory terminology:

Since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is finite, then the number of possible values of $a^n$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, is finite. In particular, there are $m_1 < m_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^{m_1} = a^{m_2}$. Since $a$ is invertible modulo $n$, there is $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $aa^{-1}=[1]$.
Therefore we have:
$$a^{m_1}(a^{-1})^{m_1} = a^{m_2}(a^{-1})^{m_1}$$
$$[1] = a^{m_2-m_1}$$
Now we just pick $k = m_2-m_1$. We have that $k\geq 1$, and $k = 1$ if, and only if $a = [1]$.

Comment: Okay I think I kind of see now. For the inverse of $a$, the $-1$ can be treated as an exponent then?

Comment: Yes. I think that a good way to see this is to detail like this:
$a^{m_2}(a^{-1})^{m1} = a^{m1}a^{m_2-m_1}(a^{-1})^{m1} = a^{m_2-m_1}(a...a)(a^{-1}...a^{-1}) = a^{m_2-m_1}$

Comment: Alright that helps, thank you!